# javascript Dropdown menu always opens at a specific location

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a javaScript Drop Down menu which i'am displaying in table row along with some other data . so when i click on the first menu button it opens like it should , slightly below the button , but when i press the menu button for the other rows of data below i the menu always opens in the position of the first row of the table .

long story short i click the dropdown menu and menu appears somewhere else away from the button .

my javascript

```
/* click on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown 
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the CSS

```
.dropbtn {
background-color: #027581;
color: white;
padding: 3.5px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 10%;}



 .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #2980B9;  }

.dropdown {
position:relative;
display:flex;
text-align: left; }



.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position:absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
max-width: 150px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1; }

show {display:block;}
```

the html

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Action ▼</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="user_profile.php">View</a>
<a href="#">Delete</a>
```

any help i appreaciated

Comment: Where is the CSS for the `.show` class?

Comment: @Steve Apologies i forgot about it , it is added now . i am displaying it as block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>On the `.dropdown-content` you are displaying it as absolute without giving it any position, so it will be at 0,0 of the first parent that is not `position:static`, so in this case the `div.dropdown`. Where you are using flex-box on that div, you can utilize `flex-direction: column` to flow the elements in a column.</s>

**EDIT:**

In a table situation, the event function is calling an ID. Since an ID needs to be unique, and you are assigning multiple elements with the same ID, the function is only finding the first element with that ID and toggling the class of that element. So in your case it will always be the first row.

In the snippet below, I adjusted it to be a table. In the event function, I pass the event. I can then get the `event.target` which is the "button" that was clicked. By adding on `.parentNode` to the end of  that (`event.target.parentNode`), it will go up the DOM one level, and get the parent of the clicked on button. You can use the querySelector on that div to find just the `div.dropdown-content` within that parent div and toggle the `.show` class.

See if the snippet below is what you are looking for.

```js
/* click on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(event) {
  const parent = event.target.parentNode;
  parent.querySelector(`.dropdown-content`).classList.toggle(`show`)
}

// Close the dropdown 
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches(`.dropbtn`)) {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.dropdown-content.show`)
      .forEach(element => element.classList.remove(`show`));
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

td:first-child {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #027581;
  color: white;
  padding: 3.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  max-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="dropbtn">Action ▼</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="user_profile.php">View</a>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Row 1 / Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 / Column 3</td>
      <td>Row 1 / Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="dropbtn">Action ▼</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="user_profile.php">View</a>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Row 2 / Column 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 / Column 3</td>
      <td>Row 2 / Column 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: didn't work , for the first row of the table the menu opens correctly but for the other rows the menu still opens in the first row at the top , like as if i pressed the first row's menu button

Comment: I updated the snippet. It is because you have more than one ID named `myDropdown`. An ID needs to be unique to the DOM. So, the JS is finding the first element with that id and performing the class toggle on it.